# WP Apache .htaccess redirect .com traffic to .co.uk Issue

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect, apache2

I have a website I am looking to redirect `.com` traffic to `.co.uk`.

For the moment, when I navigate to `https://example.com`, it redirects to `https://www.example.co.uk` and displays as such in the address bar

However when I navigate to something like `https://example.com/contact-us`, it does not redirect to the `.co.uk` equivalent.

My `.htaccess` is currently configured like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: It seems that if I navigate to http:// example.com/example it will redirect to https:// www.example.co.uk/example

Comment: But  if I navigate to https:// example.com/example, it will still display that address up in the bar, and will direct the client to https://www. example.co.uk/ when I click anything on screen

Comment: "...and will direct the client to `https://www.example.co.uk/` when I click anything on screen" - literally "anything", or when you click a link? And to the document root, `/example` is lost?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a WordPress site, you presumably have other mod_rewrite directives in your `.htaccess` file to drive the WP "pretty" permalinks.

The behaviour you are experiencing would seem to be consistent with having put the redirect directives in the wrong place, ie. *after* the WordPress front-controller<sup>***1**</sup>. This redirect must go *before* the existing WordPress directives.

<sup>***1**</sup> With the mod_rewrite redirect *after* the *default* WordPress front-controller (the mod_rewrite directives that route the request to WordPress) the redirect will only be processed for the document root and any direct request for a physical file or directory. All other requests will be "blocked" by the WP front-controller (and routed to WP) so the redirect that follows is not processed.

However, your condition is not strictly correct either, assuming you do want to canonicalise/redirect `example.co.uk` as well? Your current `RewriteCond` directive is only satisfied if the requested host is not `www.example.co.uk` and not `example.co.uk` (since you made the `www` subdomain in a negated condition. The `NC` flag should also be omitted here as well in order to redirect incorrectly cased requests for the canonical hostname.

Try the following instead, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# ... WP directives follow...
```

Redirect anything other than `www.example.co.uk` (exactly) *before* the WordPress front-controller.

Comment: How did you get on with this?